# opening swf files using WebKit framework

Tags: cocoa

Can any one tell how can i open an swf file using WebKit framework. Please specify the link which specify instructions to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't open an SWF with WebKit.

If the Flash plug-in is installed on the system, a SWF file can be loaded by the Flash plug-in if an HTML page which contains the appropriate `embed` tags is loaded into a `WebView`. If all you want to do is display Flash content, you should construct an HTML page that contains the appropriate HTML tags and load it into your `WebView`.

Note that because the Flash plug-in is not garbage-collection supported, the plug-in won't work if your application uses garbage collection.

If you actually need to open and manipulate the contents of an SWF file you'll need to do it yourself.

If you want to play Flash content without a WebView you can use the commercial [FlashInApp](http://www.swf-mac.com/cocoa-framework.html) framework, but again it won't work with garbage collection.

Comment: You can tell a WebView to load a swf file directly. It will, of course, only play if the Flash Player plug-in is installed and loadable, as you note.